# Why isn't JavaScript picking up on this error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

Rather than display the error details, the entire javascript is just not displayed. The subscripts and superscripts aren't displayed either!

```
try
{
document.write("<p>Fontsize: " + txt.fontsize(6px) + "</p>");
}
catch(err)
{
document.write("Error details: " + err);
}
document.write("<p>Subscript: " + txt.sub() + "</p>");
document.write("<p>Superscript: " + txt.sup() + "</p>");
```

Comment: What error are you expecting? Have you checked the error console?

Comment: Install firebug. You're stress level will improve.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`6px` is invalid syntax.

Therefore, the entire script is not executed.  (since it can't be parsed)

`catch` blocks catch *runtime* errors in your script.
If the script contains invalid syntax, the Javascript interpreter will throw out the entire script, because it makes no sense.
It will not try to recover whatever it can make sense out of.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that it was invalid, but why doesn't the catch pick up on it?

Comment: @DarkLight: Because it can't parse the code in the first place.

Comment: Similarly, if you write `try { "}{{}{}{}{}}}} ... } catch(e) { ... }`, it won't catch anything, because the script makes no sense.  There is no conceptual difference between that and `6px`.

Comment: @DarkLight: You can make a separate `<script>` block that checks for side effects from the first one.  If you don't see the side effects, the first one didn't parse.  That won't give you any error messages, though.

Comment: Instead, you should use a Javascript debugger, such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).